# React-Redux -- selecting item from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

New to React, I am having hard time selecting an item from a recipe list. I am working on how to delete a recipe from the list, but first I want to figure out how to select that particular recipe.

Here's an example of a well-working demo:

https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-recipe-box

As you can see, each item has its own Delete button and I have done in my code as well.

I have the following code in my container:

**src/containers/recipebox.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Panel, Button, Modals } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { deleteRecipe } from '../actions/index';

class RecipeBox extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.renderRecipeList = this.renderRecipeList.bind(this)
  }
  renderRecipeList(recipeItem,index){
    const recipe = recipeItem.recipe;
    const ingredients = recipeItem.ingredients;
    return(
      <div key={index}>
        <Panel bsStyle="primary" collapsible header={<h3>{recipe}</h3>}>
          <ListGroup >
            <ListGroupItem  header="Ingredients"></ListGroupItem>
            {ingredients.map(function(ingredient,index){
              return <ListGroupItem key={index}>{ingredient}</ListGroupItem>;
            })}
            <ListGroupItem>
              <Button
                onClick={this.props.deleteRecipe}
                value={recipeItem}
                bsStyle="danger">Delete
              </Button>
              <Button
                onClick={() => console.log('EDIT!')}
                bsStyle="info">Edit
              </Button>
            </ListGroupItem>
          </ListGroup>
        </Panel>
      </div>
    )
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className='panel-group'>
          {this.props.addRecipe.map(this.renderRecipeList)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    addRecipe : state.addRecipe
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({deleteRecipe : deleteRecipe}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RecipeBox);
```

Where my Action is as so:

**src/actions/index.js**

```
export const RECIPE_ADD = 'RECIPE_ADD';
export const RECIPE_EDIT = 'RECIPE_EDIT';
export const RECIPE_DELETE = 'RECIPE_DELETE';
export function addRecipe(recipe) {
  return {
    type: RECIPE_ADD,
    payload: recipe
  }
}
export function editRecipe(recipe) {
  return {
    type: RECIPE_EDIT,
    payload: recipe
  }
}
export function deleteRecipe(event) {
  return {
    type: RECIPE_DELETE,
    payload: event.target.value
  }
}
```

Specifically I am looking at this in my container:

```
      <Button
        onClick={this.props.deleteRecipe}
        value={recipeItem}
        bsStyle="danger">Delete
      </Button>
```

In my reducer, I am seeing as

```
payload: "[object Object]"
```

How do I use onClick event listener that will select the appropriate recipe from the list?

(note: I haven't implemented the reducer yet, I just want to see how I can see the action.payload to be the selected recipe)

EDIT:
I found the solution. Simply I needed to figure out how to pass an argument using onClick without invoking by itself.
The following ES6 code did the trick:

```
      <Button
        onClick={() => this.props.deleteRecipe(recipeItem)}
        bsStyle="danger">Delete
      </Button>
```

Cheers

Comment: The value of a button is a string. If you assign an object it will just convert it to a string. Don't use `target.value`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Simply I needed to figure out how to pass an argument using onClick without invoking by itself. The following ES6 code did the trick:

```
  <Button
    onClick={() => this.props.deleteRecipe(recipeItem)}
    bsStyle="danger">Delete
  </Button
```